# JavaScript. Создание JPG или PDF на стороне клиента

Tags: pdf, php, mjpg, javascript

Всем доброго времени суток!
В одно время была задача создания EXCEL документа ( в PHP ), и крайне не хотелось писать десятки строк кода для разметки EXCEL документа, когда в HTML уже есть сформированная таблица со стилями  и т.д. . Копал-копал и выкопал прекрасный  [скрипт](https://gist.github.com/insin/1031969)
Указываешь ему только ID-шник таблицы и вуаля, вот тебе готовый файл, только необходимо:

а) Стили прописывать в тегах, а не в  `<style></style>` (я написал ф-цию переноса из `<style></style>` в style=""),

б) Путь к картинкам указывать полный.

Ну вот сопсна и вопрос, знает кто, как создать таким же образом JPG или PDF ?
Или какие-либо библиотеки (со стороны сервера) для создания PDF, **поддерживающие кириллицу**?

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Попробуйте [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF)

Comment: Для создания картинки: html2canvas